# Using the MySQL like statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello i am trying to get the like statement working however it will only work if its an exact match where as im am hoping to show all matches. So lets say you search "and" in the search bar, i want it to come back with all posts that have the word and in the title Below is the code

```
SELECT * FROM `Posts` WHERE title LIKE 'and'
```

Just trying to get this working in the phpmyadmin with the sql tab before i bother creating the actual full script.

Does anyone know how i can get the above statement to show all posts with and in the title?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: [RTFM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to put % before and after and.

```
SELECT * FROM `Posts` WHERE title LIKE '%and%'
```

Comment: This will pick up sand and andrew

Comment: dam percentage signs haha thanks for this worked like a charm when i can i'll mark is as the answer cheers!

Comment: @Strawberry You can put a space before and after it.

Comment: That'll miss "And" at the beginning and end of sentences. But you're getting there.

Comment: Sentences shouldn't begin, or end with "and". ;)

Comment: As you like it ;-) (Act 2 Scene 1)

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
SELECT * FROM `Posts` WHERE title LIKE '% and %'
```

Doing something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `Posts` WHERE title LIKE '%and%'
```

will include anything with `and` in it; `sandy`, for example.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, i think i will use the % and % for the first run, if that doesn't show any results do the %and% for the recommended ones, thanks for the help.

Comment: If you need case insensitive search, use LOWER(title) LIKE '% and %'.

Answer (score 1):

```
try this placing % symbol
SELECT * FROM `Posts` WHERE title LIKE '%and%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `Posts` WHERE title LIKE '%and%'
```

MySQL provides two **wildcard** characters for using with the LIKE operator, the percentage **%** and underscore **_**.

The percentage ( `%`) wildcard allows you to match any string of zero or more characters.
The underscore ( `_`) wildcard allows you to match any single character

Suppose you want to search for posts whose title starts with character ‘ **and**‘, you can use the percentage wildcard ( `%`) at the end of the pattern

```
SELECT * FROM `Posts` WHERE title LIKE '%and%'
```

If you know the searched string is embedded inside in the column, you can use the percentage ( `%`) wildcard at the beginning and the end of the pattern

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `Posts` FROM books WHERE title REGEXP '[[:<:]]and[[:>:]]';
```

Comment: is this a better way of doing it?

Comment: _Better_ is subjective. If you put 20 programmers in a room and give them a problem, you will get 20 different solutions; it's all about which of those solutions is better for _you_.

Comment: By better i mean faster and less stress on the system :) yes that .1 millisecond counts haha

Comment: @jphillip724: Probably, yes. This answer saves you running more than one query as you mentioned before. Personally, I would have accepted this answer as correct, but that's your decision.

Answer (score 0):

With this fiddle you are going to learn the differences when you use the wildcard operator(%):

```
select bar from foo where bar like "%h";
select bar from foo where bar like "%h%";
select bar from foo where bar like "h%";
```

Check the result here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1bc45f/2