# variables in mysql like statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello i am trying to get a like statment working, i asked a question on here about an hour ago see [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22995739/using-the-mysql-like-statement?__=1458859697#22995815) however that was using static content my intention was that this would easily be changeable by just using _GET to get the search term from the input and creating a variable from that.

however it doesnt work, at the moment i have this

```
$search = $_GET['search'];
"SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE title LIKE '% $search %'"
```

and i have tried the following

```
"SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE title LIKE '"% $search %"'"
"SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE title LIKE '%" $search "%'"
"SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE title LIKE '%" .$search. "%' "
```

can any one help me get a variable working with the like statement? thank you for the help.

Comment: what do you mean when you say "it doesn't work"?  What does it do instead?

Comment: It doesn't do anything no error message nothing, the rest of the page renders fine, and i know the search term should ping up a result.

Comment: please post your actual PHP source, so we can see how you're executing the query.

Comment: please post the complete code including the query execution part.

Comment: Please don't use un-sanitized user data in your SQL queries. Take a moment to educate yourself on the risk of [SQL Injection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and how to protect yourself from it.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty your one worked i just had to clear cache please post it again so i can mark it as the right answer.

Comment: @tkocmathla this is for a university project where we need to use mysql_ and securing the data we get 0 extra marks, with a dissertation to write for one months time, i just want the project over and done with, i would use mysqli or pdo but the uni doesn't let you (i know weird?) if this was for a real site/client data would 100% be sanitized

Comment: Your uni doesn't let _you_ write secure code? Horseshit.

Comment: @TheBlueDog sorry i said that wrong, the site is for a "ethical" hacking class, and we have to make it as vulnerable as possible to demonstrate 5 of the 10 OWASP variabilities, sanitising the data would give me a harder time to demonstrate them since the idea is to make it as vulnerable as possible (then write a white paper on how to prevent them etc), the uni only uses mysql_ hell they still use FLASH over jquery (don't even ask)

Comment: @jphillip724: Oh, ok. LOL @ "Ethical Hacking" though ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE title LIKE '%".$search."%'"
```

Comment: can u post the complete code how u are executing the query ?

Comment: It did work i just had to clear cache haha thanks dam white space :(

Comment: u can use trim() to remove those white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the spaces between the `%`-signs and the `$search`-variable:

```
LIKE '% $search %'
```

to

```
LIKE '%$search%'
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using php, and want to retrieve the variable in another file, try using $ _POST:

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE title LIKE '%".$search."%'";
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. `$_POST` is for HTTP POST data as opposed to data sent by an HTTP GET request.